# how to replace whole column characters as asterix based on length of a column in Mysql or snowflake

Tags: mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have a value

```
'sam/le' length --> 6 

'add\$io&alsample' length --> 16
```

i need to replace all characters as  **'*'**

i used  `select regexp_replace(substr('asdfasdndfs',4),'\w','*')`
it only replaces alphabets

desired output

| id | col | replaced col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sam/le | ****** |
| 2 | add$io&alsample | **************** |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually wanting to make the update after adding that as a new column:

```
UPDATE strings SET replaced_col = LPAD('', CHAR_LENGTH(col), '*')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lpad(''              -- start with empty string
    ,len(yourColumn) -- pad to the length of your column text
    ,'*'             -- with asterisks
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [REPEAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/repeat.html):

```
SELECT id, col, REPEAT('*', LEN(col))
FROM tab
```